# Print default logo on mobile printer zonerich AB-320M

Tags: java-me, mobile, printers

I´m trying to put a default logo to this mobile printer (Zonerich AB-320M) http://www.zonerich.com/english/ab-320m.htm , I mean we need that everytime we send to print, the printer itselfs print the content with a default logo at the top of the page... I already have a **J2ME** app that print but I cannot set a default image... is this possible or I'm wasting my time...

[UPDATE]

Hi Guys I finally found how to do this, I have to write to zonerich and they give me an app that download a BMP image to the printer memory, and them with this HEX command we select the image logo and it works...

1C 70 i 30 where "i" is the position on memory of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

Hi Guys I finally found how to do this, I have to write to zonerich and they give me an app that download a BMP image to the printer memory, and them with this HEX command we select the image logo and it works...

1C 70 i 30 where "i" is the position on memory of the logo.

Comment: Do you have complete HEX command set? If you do, could you send it to me?